# VS/Pylance Jupyter Notebook warning: import could not be resolved

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I'm getting this warning: `Import "module" could not be resolved`
I think it has to be something related to the environment.
I'm using VSCode for a Jupyter Notebook and Anaconda. I think I should somehow align the environments. If I select in the right top corner the Anaconda kernel I can run but sometimes I have problems with paths.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

folks.

I've found a workaround for this issue. In the project root folder, create a subfolder ".vscode" (without quotes) and a file settings.json insiste it. Edit the json file and configure python.analysis.extraPaths of the current project like:

```
{
"python.analysis.extraPaths": [ "path_to_venv_import_pakages" ],
}
```

I'm working in a local project with Jupyter notebook files and conda venv enviroment, so settings.json looks like:

```
{
  "python.analysis.extraPaths": [ "D:\Users\hs\Envs\udemyDSPy\lib\site-packages" ],
}
```

As the config is specific to project, we can change this in other projects to point the right venv packages import location. I hope it works for you.

*Note.: I'm using VSCode 1.64.2 version.

Answer (score 1):

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71315932/14941949) of [Humberto Samora](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18348455/humberto-samora) perfectly solved my problem and I'd like to supplement a little.
The default path of your venv shuold be `C:/Users/[your_username]/anaconda3/envs/` and use **slash** instead of backslash in the path.

```
{
  "python.analysis.extraPaths": [ "C:/Users/[your_username]/anaconda3/envs/[your_venv]/Lib/site-packages" ],
}
```